# Alternative to Calendar Overlays

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, view

I have a calendar list in a SharePoint 2010 enterprise site which uses a few other calendars as overlays. When I view it in Calendar View all is fine - the events from the other calendars are showing up as expected.

However, when I change to All or Current Events view, these events don't show up. Is there any way of showing aggregated events from other calendars in a All/Current Events view?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The list view of the calendar is specific to the one list, sadly the overlays only work on the calendar views. What you can do is include a Content Query Web Part or a Search Results web part, filtered on your event content type and/or lists and display them that way. It won't be the most elegant method, but it'll work.

This post might help get you started using a CQWP: http://blog.pointycandy.com/2012/03/content-query-web-part-cqwp-and-events.html